# React-Leaflet automated coordinate extraction/generation based on an image

Tags: javascript, automation, leaflet, coordinates, react-leaflet

I’m attempting to create a seating diagram using React Leaflet 2.7.0. I’ve made the coordinates relative to the Map bounds by setting the crs property to `L.CRS.Simple`.

I know how to create and place vector circles by manually inputting coordinates to represent a seat. This method allows the shapes to scale proportionately when zoomed (rather than using Markers, which don’t scale).  My challenge is finding a way to efficiently determine coordinates based on an image of a seating chart.

I’m wondering if anyone knows of a way to extract coordinates based on an image to say a geoJson or Javascript object; Perhaps a plugin or other third-party, or built-in Leaflet feature I’m not aware of.

The image shows the concept of what I’m trying to achieve.
desired concept:
  [image]

Answer (score -2):

what I normally do is, create an event that when *onclick* it would gather the coordinates related to the image and after that push it to an array which after I finish I can console log the array which I just copy-paste to my text editor